# Read data from Serial port of Windows 10 host on Virtual box Ubuntu 16.04 guest

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, serial-port, virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 as guest OS on Virtual Box on Windows 10 host. I have connected an Arduino Board on COM5 of host, which streams xml element continuously. I can verify that it is streaming data on the puTTY window. 
Problem: I want to bridge this data from COM5 which can be accessed on puTTY window on the guest. In future I am writing a Python code where I am accessing the data from the xml element and use it for the project.

I tried doing this:
*VirtualBox->Settings->Serial Ports->Port 1->Checked 'Enable Serial Port*

Port Number = COM1 (Guest OS Port, which can be accessed as /dev/ttyS0)
Port Mode = Host Device
Path/Address = COM5 ( since I have connected to COM5, I think I am wrong here...)

But no help, when I tried to access using puTTY.
If some one can explain me the process of doing this, that would be great.